# Develop a Login function with WhatsApp QR

Tags: node.js, integration, qr-code, whatsapp

From the [WhatsApp Encryption Overview docs](https://scontent.fkul16-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/384251896_820338303082371_8514785982310046047_n.pdf?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=e280be&_nc_ohc=fFGBbptKVooAX8v-CGo&_nc_oc=AQkom2Ndggh-YUg5RtJeoABx0NlFITjJizLErmwn_x8p2sVjrUbg1oP7kNwZzAKWOdI&_nc_ht=scontent.fkul16-2.fna&oh=00_AfBd5RnUpK5loNiagyP6QSm9SWyzfyCqYsJ-G6nUyIz0mA&oe=65EFCDD1), I noticed that "Companion Devices" and other platforms such as [ChatDaddy](https://www.chatdaddy.tech/service/whatsapp-api) have their QR generated by a Curve25519 computed over 0x600/0x601.

All of those QR resulted in something like this:
`2@M+9bxTnWDsocS7ODEoM8sIAje3N6Ejy3vvtGhqoOVZKDxdyTrnEvk6HpmEpnl01FMLZlBFJYYXgz6Q==,XZx4ui0ast87hjlX5Dd5icn0qYA+mi2D5n5vW5NMVkU=,YDhfWsv0xMf5Jx6hfBIgmMXwvdN+mNMiQ2dpB+MNzBI=,nM5ABBnEtt2A9IZb9C6skrUcjraU4c0ggUkPJuOIXsk=,1`

`2@hjOu4dJ5hQ1JXvZJk9T0uTcEubaA4qhGkUJntTQKAcyr1bTjx98Z9J6r4TQw9ZSam2GuI5cVxAMC9g==,XZx4ui0ast87hjlX5Dd5icn0qYA+mi2D5n5vW5NMVkU=,YDhfWsv0xMf5Jx6hfBIgmMXwvdN+mNMiQ2dpB+MNzBI=,nM5ABBnEtt2A9IZb9C6skrUcjraU4c0ggUkPJuOIXsk=,1`

What are the keys after the "comma" (,) represented as? And how do I get the similar keys like this that has the same length in everything including the "2@", the "equals" (=), and the "double equals" at the first sequence (==)?

I'm trying to do the same thing in NodeJS using crypto library and the results were pretty close.

```js
const alice = crypto.createDiffieHellman(600);
alice.generateKeys();
console.log("Signature:", alice.getPrivateKey().toString("base64"));
```

Output:
`Signature: SxVeIFSniYhDN9Jfq5jB0VnOWICod8laI1RjsS+oRMe/ULHp6+VzAb0f08nfUEuOcW1NmJ5FRYtxrw603EDDmeZ9vs3VQ5zDv6b+`